# Is it possible to customise the BigBlueButton's video chat layout?

Tags: html5-video, http-live-streaming, videochat, bigbluebutton

I need to develop an application for online learning and live teaching.
I google and found **[BigBlueButton](https://bigbluebutton.org)** which is used by most of the live teaching platform.

But I found all the apps which are using the BigBlueButton have the same old UI for Video chat or live chat.

I also found the are working new HTML5 which have good design but It's not production read.

My Question is:

> Can I customise the [BigBlueButton](https://demo.bigbluebutton.org/b) and design some cool UI using HTML5 or using the latest HTML5 Design with previous flash plugins.

Answer (score 0):

We've been working on an upgrade to BigBlueButton with a more modern UI design.  You can see more information here in a [recent post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/bigbluebutton-dev/eq8u4ZpGb-w/RUbNZ6dZCwAJ) to bigbluebutton-dev mailing list.

We are also working on an HTML5 that will interoperate with the Flash client (instructors won't care whether a student connects via Flash or HTML5).  For more information see: http://docs.bigbluebutton.org/html/html5-overview.html.